# how to install tensorflow on a spark HDInsight cluster?

Tags: python, apache-spark, tensorflow, pyspark, azure-hdinsight

I am trying to install tensorflow on a spark HDInsight cluster. but facing issues.

I used pip install tensorflow from the headnode.

I am able to import tensorflow from the python.

```
Python 2.7.12 (default, Dec  4 2017, 14:50:18)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import tensorflow
>>> exit()
```

But when I try to import tensorflow from head node or pyspark console it is throwing an error

```
SPARK_MAJOR_VERSION is set to 2, using Spark2
Python 2.7.12 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:42:40)
[GCC 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-1)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel).
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.0.2.2.5.6.2-9
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.12 (default, Jul  2 2016 17:42:40)
SparkSession available as 'spark'.
>>> import tensorflow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named tensorflow
```

Can anyone please help me with installing tensorflow on spark HDinsight cluster.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with HDInsight in particular, but it looks like your pyspark is running on top of Anaconda. Perhaps you should `conda install tensorflow` in the appropriate location of your system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a script action to install TensorFlow on the head nodes and worker nodes with the instructions found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/spark/apache-spark-python-package-installation) under the "Use external packages with Jupyter notebooks" section, a TensorFlow bash script is provided

Comment: Thanks I will give it a try.